# running into permission issues when using the COPY command with postgresql 14.6-1 on linux 6.0.12-arch1-1

Tags: linux, permissions, arch-linux, sql, postgresql

Hello everyone :) noob here,
trying to learn sql with postgresql 14.6-1 on arch linux kernel: 6.0.12-arch1-1 ,
the current topic of the book i'm reading, has me doing this command

```sql
COPY char_data_types TO '/home/user/path/to/file.txt'
    WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, DELIMITER '|');
```

but i am getting this error:

```
[2022-12-13 18:49:30] [42501] ERROR: could not open file "/home/user/path/to/file.txt" for writing: Permission denied
[2022-12-13 18:49:30] Hint: COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```

I thought I could get around this by fiddling around with the directory permissions I was trying to write to so i tried a couple of things, like created the file first and then allowed write permissions on it to all with `chmod a+rwx` or to the directory where i was tyring to have postgres create the file, even created a directory and did `chown directory postgres; chgrp directory postgress` and still an error.

interestingly when i logon as the `postgres` user by doing `sudo -iu postgres` i seem to not have access to any directory outside of `/var/lib/postgres/data` (by not having access i mean not being able to write files with `touch`, and even more i am not able to actually cd into any subdirectory in `/home`). I also gave added the `postgres` user to the `users` and `wheel` groups by doing `usermod -aG users postgres; usermod -aG wheel postgres;` but still same error , i even gave it root access but still no luck.

At the postgres side of thngs, I did a couple of postgres commands while in the psql shell that i found online that i thought could help was to run a couple of `GRANT` commands. i can't remember all of them but here is the output of the psql when I run `\du`

```
postgres=# \du
                                                 List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         |              Member of               
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 malup     | Superuser                                                  | {pg_read_all_data,pg_write_all_data}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {pg_read_all_data,pg_write_all_data}
```

But still same error.

I found a quick a suggestion to just write the file to `/tmp` directory so i don't have to mess with permissions. when i do that, i don't get the error, but the file is not there for some reason. I don't know what's going on about that.

The only way i was able to find success in having the `COPY` command actually write to a file is if i do pass in the `postgres/data` dir in the command instead:

```sql
COPY char_data_types TO '/var/lib/postgres/data/file.txt'
    WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, DELIMITER '|');
```

Is there a way to to actually allow this postgres to write to other user directories in my system? i don't think it's a file-permission-related issue anymore.

I also am aware that that i can use the `\copy` from psql but I want to try it from an sql script.

Answer (score 1):

### if not using `/tmp`,  enable access to postgres server user from root down, not just parent directory

Postgres could read from `/tmp` directory, but the 50+ 2GB unzipped files would not fit there.  A subdirectory under /home/user was used instead.  In order for PostGRES server to read this with `COPY FROM`, permissions were needed to be granted all the way the tree to root `/`, not just parent directory.

### disable SeLINUX¹

For the same problem on Redhat RHEL 8.8:

`SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: could not open file "/tmp/a.csv" for reading: Permission denied Hint: COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.`
I tried moving the file, operating as the `postgres` superuser, nothing worked until **I [disabled SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/changing-selinux-states-and-modes_using-selinux)**.

`COPY FROM` directly on the server is key to making this solution viable.  These massive 100Gb tables load fastest directly from server, which is why client-side `psql \copy` or trying to pipeline to cloud server were not feasible.  The PostGRESQL PaaS setup required to match this Ryzen 7 / AM5 nvmE bare metal solution proved to be prohibitively expensive for what are batch transformations happening once or twice a month.

¹*Security caveats apply*.  (In this case it's an offline, dedicated-to-purpose server on a private network that runs only to digest and analyze very large tables, then is shut down.)

Comment: thanks for the tmp hint, that was enough for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

> (by not having access i mean not being able to write files with touch, and even more i am not able to actually cd into any subdirectory in /home). I also gave added the postgres user to the users and wheel groups by doing usermod -aG users postgres; usermod -aG wheel postgres; but still same error , i even gave it root access but still no luck.

you've basically explained the problem yourself. the postgres user can't cd in to the needed directory, because a parent directory denies access to the postgres user.

if you file is in /test/foo/bar/file.txt you cant access file.txt, even if the user has access to bar/, as long as the user has no access to foo/

the easiest solution would be if you write the output to either a "public" directory like /tmp or some custom special dir, e.g. /var/mycustomscript/export.sql, and giving the postgres user access to that directory.

I *STRONGLY*  discourage you from putting stuff like this somewhere like home directories.

In general it seems like you still lack a bit of knowladge regarding liux file perms (which is ok, everyone has to start, we don't get born with that wisdome :D ). I encourage you to try reading up on how that works :)

Comment: Detailed info: For a user to be able to access a directory, it needs execute permissions to it. thats th x in rwxrwx-rx ./foo/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else still looking into this:
This seems to be a common issue for users following these sorts of tutorials on all OSs. The main issue in Linux is that it seems you can really let the postgres user access the /home/ directory.
I'm not sure what issue the op was having with the /tmp folder. But, in my case, the simple solution was to: 1. move the CSV to /tmp/. 2. Right click CSV and go to Properties, set Permissions: for "Others" Access: "Read and write".